# Sum of geometric points on large interval

Tags: algorithm, intervals

I have a large interval `[0 ... 2^32 - 1]`. There are approximately 2^20 points with some coordinate and value, for example:

```
1; 435
5; 5454
345345; 5485;
9999999; 43435
4294967294; 35353
```

Also I have set of intervals. Number of intervals is less than `2^22`. For example,

```
1 3; // sum is 435
1 3535; // sum is 435 + 5454
99994 4294967294; // sum is 5485 + 43435 + 35353
```

For each interval I have to calculate sum modulo `2^32`.

There is naive algorithm. I can iterate over all points for each interval. It is require O(number of queries * number of points). It is too slow.

Is there more quicker algorithm?

Comment: I think that upon reading the structure can be prepared, so that you can compute the needed sum in O(1). So the query would take O(2*ln N) operations. But it looks like a contest entry.

Comment: well you can easily do better than the naive solution by sorting the point list and using a binary search, but I'm guessing there's something faster. how much memory can you use?

Comment: @japreiss, I tried this way. It is also slow. I can use 256 RAM.

Comment: Are the sums inclusive on the upper end?  In other words, would the sum of `1 5` be `435` or `435 + 5454`?

Comment: @japreiss, sums are inclusive on the upper end. Sum of `1 5` is `435 + 5454`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the points. Iterate over the points and compute the running sum of the values up to each point. Store the sums in an array. When you want to compute the sum for an interval, find the lower and upper limit by binary search, then look up the lower sum and upper sum. The difference of these sums is the sum for the interval.

For the example you gave, the points are indexed as follows:

```
{0: 1, 1: 5, 2: 345345, 3: 9999999, 4: 4294967294}
```

The sums are the following:

```
{0: 0, 1: 435, 2: 5889, 3: 11374, 4: 54809, 5: 90162}
```

To calculate the sum in the interval `[a..b]`, find the indices `p(a)` and `p(b)` of the smallest points that are no bigger than `a` and `b`, and return `sums[p(b)+1] - sums[p(a)]`.

For 1 and 3, we find the indices 0 and 0. The result is `sums[1] - sums[0]`.

For 1 and 3535, we find the indices 0 and 1. The result is `sums[2] - sums[0]`.

For 99994 and 4294967294, we find the indices 2 and 4. The result is `sums[5] - sums[2]`.

It takes O(number of points) to prepare the array of sums. Each query takes O(log(number of points)).